# Touch Up Inside for a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I'm trying to implement touch event similar to a `Touch Up Inside` a `UIButton`. I've seen some codes using `touchesBegan:withEvent` but it looks I need to slide a bit my finger over the screen. I actually just want to touch in the image

Code:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {   
    NSLog(@"Image touched!");
}
```

Regards!

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't just use a `UIButton` with custom style and an image?

Comment: Actually no, but I wonder if there is any other way to do it.

Comment: If you don't need the features that `UIButton` provides, you can instead subclass or use the more bare-bones `UIControl` directly. `UIControl` takes care of all the nasty touch state management, so you don't have to. Doing it yourself also means your UI will behave slightly differently to all other apps, which might be confusing to the user.

Comment: @pmjordan Yes, you need to use `UIImage` if you're using Interface Builder and you want to control the layout of the image (Aspect Fit, Aspect Fill, etc.)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could use the **gesture** to get the touch on `UIImageView`.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                         initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ClickEventOnImage:)];
        [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];
        [tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
        //Don't forget to set the userInteractionEnabled to YES, by default It's NO.
        myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [myImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

Implement the  `ClickEventOnImage` function.

```
-(void) ClickEventOnImage:(id) sender
{

}
```

Comment: That rocks.  In the handler method, you can get the location of the tap by querying the gesture recognizer using locationInView:(UIView*)view; in a scrollview, the returned coordinate includes the scrolled content offset.

Comment: We should probably autorelease the tapRecognizer, to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @Ron : yes Ron .. I missed that  thanks for pointing out ...Or may be after adding it into imageview we could release it ...

Comment: Do not forget to add <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> to the interface (.h)

Answer (score 6):

`UIImageView` is notorious regarding this as its `userInteractionEnabled` is set to `NO` by default. You will have to enable it by doing

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

And then you can use gesture recognizers or the normal `touches*` methods to handle touches.