# Int Value from MainViewController to UIImageView Class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, integer

i want to use a Integer Value from my MainViewController.m in some UIImageView objects that i created. I used the TapRecognizer in my UIImageView Class. when i tap on one of the Images on the Screen, my Value in my MainViewController.m should count up.

The code for the TapRecognizer is running. I tried it with NSLog Code and it worked. So how can i get a MainView Integer Value in this UIImageView Class File? 
Can someone help me please?

**EDIT:**

I've tried nothing so far. I've just set up the gesture recognizer. I used this code: ["Touch up inside for a UIImageView"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372505/touch-up-inside-for-a-uiimageview) . This code is inside my UIImageView.m . All i want is that when i tap on one of the images, a int Value of the MainViewController should could up so i can use this Value in my MainViewController

Comment: Paste the code you tried so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given by JoeFryer is one idea or else you can also use `NSNotificationCenter`.

It works as below.

Put this in `ImageviewController` Tap Action.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"countUp" object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

Put this in `MainViewController`'s `ViewDidLoad` method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(increaseCount) name:@"countUp" object:nil];
```

and also this method

```
-(void)increaseCount{
    //Here You can increase the count
    count++;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use delegation. Declare a delegate protocol, then set your MainViewController as the delegate of your UIImageView objects, then send a message from your UIImageViews to their delegate from you TapRecognizer handler.